# Using Evernote API, how can I get notes that were created within a specified date range?

Tags: api, evernote

How can I use the Evernote search grammer to get notes that were created within a specified date range?

The [documentation](http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/evernote-api.htm#_Toc296508873) has the following:

```
created:[datetime] - will match any note that has a 'created' timestamp that is equal to, or more recent than, the provided datetime
```

But has nothing on how to use date ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a second, negated created term:

To find notes created between January 1, 2010 and January 31, 2011:

created:20110101 -created:20110201

Answer (score 0):

There is a summary with some examples here:
[blog.gotofritz.net/geekery/advanced-evernote-search](http://blog.gotofritz.net/geekery/advanced-evernote-search/)